# How to pause Asynchronous Method?

Tags: c#

How can I pause Asynchronous Methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) in the worker method. Of course this would be a waste of thread resources because while it is paused it is not doing any useful work and threads are meant to do useful work :-)

Comment: Not necessarily a good idea (as both Darin and Brian point out) as this keeps a thread occupied doing nothing useful. One of the reasons for using asynchronous methods is to reduce resource usage by allowing work to the efficiently scheduled across threads. A possible solution is to use: await TaskEx.Delay(...), which will not use any threads whilst waiting. However, depending on how this is implemented, this may introduce a problem of having too many active timers, especially with large parallel software. (TaskEx.Delay() is in async CTP - I believe this may change to Task.Delay() in RTM)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options: As @Darin points out, you can use Thread.Sleep, which is useful if you want to wait for a specific duration and not occupy the core in question while doing so. If you want to wait for a very short time [Thread.SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx) may be a better option, as you can avoid the context switch associated with Sleep. If you want to wait for a specific event, you can use an [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx).